# which nodejs library is for AWS opensearch client?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am planning to use `opensearch` hosted by AWS. I found there are two libraries `@aws-sdk/client-opensearch and @opensearch-project/opensearch`. I wonder which one I should use. Are there meant to be very different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're both useful for different things.

Most likely you're interested in the actual opensearch features, like adding items to the index, updating the index, searching against the index. In this case you'll find `@opensearch-project/opensearch` useful. [These AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/request-signing.html#request-signing-node) are helpful if this is what you're digging into.

If you're looking to get information about the deployed domain, and to manage it, then `@aws-sdk/client-opensearch` may be useful.

Comment: What about elasticsearch node package?